# Цвет SVG бекграунда

Tags: css, svg

Вставляю маскировку в CSS вот так:

```
.icon {
mask-size: 100%;
mask-repeat: no-repeat;
mask-image: url('image.svg');
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
background-color: red;
}
```

Тем самым изображение перекрашивается в красный, как сделать тоже самое, но используя только `background-image: url('image.svg');`

Comment: Через `filter` и изменение HSB-составляющей (по простому цветность, яркость, насыщенность, вроде так): `filter: hue-rotate(40deg) saturate(0.5) brightness(390%) saturate(4);`

Comment: @user276524 иконка base64 ? код бы ещё посмотреть Добавьте пожалуйста, если конечно хотите решение получить